# Subversion - Set the folder to look in for repos? (server/repositoryname instead of server/var/svnroot/repositoryname)

Tags: svn

Right now I am using an absolute path to connect i.e.

```
server/var/svnroot/repositoryname
```

I would like to be able to do

```
/server/repoistoryname
```

Is there a way to set this up? I would like to avoid symmlinks since that adds overhead. I would rather just have SVN automatically goto the folder similar to how the DocumentRoot works with Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run svnserve, use the `-r` option to set the "root" path.  So in your example, launch svnserve like this: `svnsrve -r /var/svnroot`.  Of course you'll want to add your options (`-d`, `--listen-host`, etc) in there as well...